# How to I save value (int) from a webpage and store it an array using Selenium-Python

Tags: python, arrays, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to store a couple of integers which are present in a webpage and store it in a array and then find mean/avg of all the values.

I'm using

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('some_Xpath').text()
```

you could suggest any other method as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>17</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

wish to copy the value and save it in an array
I want this text to be saved in an array and then print it.
I'm new to Selenium-python. Can someone help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there multiple locations where the integers are present or a single one

Comment: multiple locations where the integers are present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to use `find_elements` (whith an **s** to retrieve all the values) in Selenium.
Based on your sample you should use :

```
ar=[int(val.text) for val in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td[3]')]
```

Then compute the mean with (be sure to `import statistics`) :

```
print(statistics.mean(ar))
```

Piece of code (with `LXML`) :

```
data = """your_html_data"""

import statistics 
import lxml.html
tree = html.fromstring(data)

# create arrays (two ways of doing it, "ar1" is the one you should use if you work with Selenium)
ar1=[int(val.text) for val in tree.xpath("//tr/td[3]")]
ar2=[int(val) for val in tree.xpath("//tr/td[3]/text()")]

# display the arrays
print(ar1)
print(ar2)

# display the means
print(statistics.mean(ar1))
print(statistics.mean(ar2))
print(tree.xpath("sum(//tr/td[3]) div count(//tr/td[3])"))
```

The last line is another option, i.e. : compute the mean directly with XPath.

Output :

```
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
14.5
14.5
14.5
```

If you need a more robust XPath, you can go with :

```
//tr/td[count(//th[.="Value"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

The computed position index of the `td` element is relative to the position of the "Value" header.

Comment: The data I have is a source of the html (driver.page_source)
When I try this code `tree = lxml.html.fromstring(table)
ar2=[int(val) for val in tree.xpath("//*[@id='ResultContainer']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/span")]
print(ar2)
print(statistics.mean(ar2))`

Comment: I get an error  I get an error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/AkshayKhard/private/metrics_calc.py", line 69, in <module>
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(table)
  File "C:\Users\AkshayKhard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 874, in fromstring
    is_full_html = _looks_like_full_html_unicode(html)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: You should use the appropriate parser then. `import lxml.etree; import StringIO; source = driver.page_source; parser = etree.HTMLParser(); tree = etree.parse(StringIO(source), parser)`

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how exactly the data you're scraping off the page looks like. The biggest struggles in scraping are actually data sanitation and is what you're also doing here.

The way you're getting the element is correct, just enter into chrome developer tools, inspect the element you want to scrape, and copy the xpath of the element.

If the element you are scraping is just a string containing multiple values (I think this is unlikely, most likely the values you're trying to get are in separate elements, but you can scrape a div that contains them all, still using `.text()`, and you will get a string containing the values) then you can just use `.split()` on the resulting string and it will be split by whitespace.

Then, combine with a list comprehension

`my_int_array = [int(val) for val in scraped_string.split()]`

and you have an array of integers.

For the exact case you've posted in your question, I would scrape the entire table and then use BeautifulSoup4 to extract the values.
Use selenium to get the `.innerHTML()` of the table, then use beautifulsoup to parse that html data. [BeautifulSoup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Thanks Chiorean, I want to copy integer value from a table which is present in the webpage.

Comment: I suggest you scrape the entire table, then process the resulting data in python code. This could be a little more complicated than scraping each element individually, but it would be more efficient as each element scraping call takes a bit of time (If performance is not an issue, then it could be ok to do this as well)